# HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError encountered when load testing is running via Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I was running one load test on Linux by using Jmeter, I have already set the JVM_ARGS="-Xms4096m -Xmx6144m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" in jmeter.sh file. However, during the test in Jmeter NON-GUI mode (./jmeter -n -t  /home/user/ss.jmx), I saw one Error by commanding "ps -ef | grep java" which is

---

`29710 29708  9 19:34 pts/1    00:00:07 java -server -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=2 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=600000 -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -jar ./ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t /home/user/ss.jmx`

---

Why are the Xms and Xmx values still 512m instead of the ones in jmeter.sh file? How to solve this error? Would this error affect the test?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a separate `jmeter` script (without `.sh` extension). Seems like you're somehow running Jmeter from that script.

Comment: Yes, I saw it too... I should use bash jmeter.sh instead of ./jmeter            Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that you changed the settings in "jmeter.bat" which is the window batch script. When you run "jmeter", you run the bash script (for linux distributions). Can you make sure you changed the right settings.
-Alon.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention I did also add JVM_ARGS="-Xms4096m -Xmx6144m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" in jmeter.sh file.